# How to set up a dynamic grid based on flex or grid

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid, grid-layout, styled-components

I want to create a dynamic grid system that should behave like this:
first when there is only 1 item it should have a width and height of 100%.

When the second child has been dynamically added to the grid it should have a height of 100% and the 2 items both 50% width.

When the THIRD item has been added the first 2 items should have a height 0f 50% and a width of 50%, the third item should have a height of 50% and a width of 100%.

Fourth item should then again have a width of 50% and height 50%.

[image: Example]

fifth item again 100% width and all the items should have 33,33% height. No matter how many items are added the grid should always behave the same way.

Currently i have:

```
const StyledVideoContainer = styled.div`
  ${({ number }) => `
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(${number}, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, 100%);

    .videoContent {
      flex-grow: 1;
    }
  `}
`;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with flexbox like below:

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* enable the wrap */
  margin:5px;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

.container>* {
  flex-basis: 50%; /* width = 50% */
  flex-grow: 1; /* grow if alone in the last row */
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

It would be a bit tricky with CSS grid but you can do it like below:

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr; /* 2 columns */
  grid-auto-rows:1fr; /* equal rows */
  margin:5px;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

.container>* {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.container>*:nth-child(odd):last-child {
  grid-column:span 2; /* take 2 columns */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```